# NSMutableArray: is it faster to remove all objects or to init a new NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

Even though this has minimal impact on my code right now I would like to understand if an operation is more costly than the other :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's faster to remove all objects. The costly thing about a NSMutableArray is extending it's internal list when it runs out of capacity.

Have a look at this [blog post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/nsarray-or-nsset-nsdictionary-or.html).

Comment: So if you re-initialize with an exact (new) capacity, would it still be faster to remove all objects from an array with a non-exact capacity and risk have it extend it's internal list?

Comment: Hmmm, that's a nice question, I suppose that when you remove all objects it doesn't reduce it's capacity. But create a big array, like 1 million entries and test it out. I would like to see some numbers. But without any doubt it would be faster to create a new array with the right capacity since the beginning.